# How can I simplify regex `/\.\.\/|\\|(?<!\.)\/|:|\*|\?|"|<|>|\|/g`?

Tags: regex

I managed to construct this regex:

```js
/\.\.\/|\\|(?<!\.)\/|:|\*|\?|"|<|>|\|/g;
```

It matches `../`, `/`, `\`, but not `./` .
Can someone help me to simplify it?
P.S I know that my syntax is wordy, but don't know how to achieve the same effect with smaller amount of symbols.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only thing I can see you can shorten is to group the single-character options into a character class; this not only saves the `|`, but means you don't have to do so much escaping, as not much has a special meaning inside a character class. So `\\|:|\*|\?|"|<|>|\|` becomes `[\\:*?"<>|]`

If your regex flavour allows it, you can also use a delimiter other than `/` (`#` is quite common, and not used in your pattern) to save a few more escapes.

That leaves you with `#\.\./|(?<!\.)/|[\\:*?"<>|]#g`

Not exactly pretty, but then regex rarely is :)